# How to group days in a week, like a calendar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that has a column of schedule, I would like to pivot on the Day_Name column so that the dates are displayed as columns like Monday, Tuesday etc.
this is my query:

```
SELECT 
     Month_Name,Day_Name, Year, Week_Number, Day_Number
    , isnull((Select (CONVERT(varchar(5), empschedfrom, 108) + '-' + convert(varchar(5), empschedto, 108)) from empdayscheds where empno = '0030' and empday_no = DayNumber_of_Month and empday_month = Month_Number and empday_year = Year), 'OFF') as emp_sched  
    from dtRule where DATE between '05/28/2017' and '07/08/2017'
```

output:

```
   Month_Name | Day_Name | Year | Week_Number |Day_number| emp_sched 
   May        |Sunday    | 2017 | 4           | 28       | 11:45-20:45
   May        | Tuesday  | 2017 | 5           | 29       | 14:15-23:15
   May        | Wednesday| 2017 | 5           | 30       | 13:45-22:45
   June       | Thursday | 2017 | 1           |  1       |10:00-19:00
   June       | Friday   | 2017 | 1           |  2       |10:00-19:00
   June       | Saturday | 2017 | 1           |  3       |10:00-19:00
```

I would like it to come out like this:

```
Week_Number | Month_Name | Year | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday  | Friday    | Saturday
1           | June       | 2017 |        |         |           |10:00-19:00|10:00-19:00|10:00-19:00
```

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: MS SQL Sever TSQL

Comment: Since you have a finite number of month_name (Jan - Dec), you can use Pivot in SQL SERVER and then group by the week_number. Need to see what you have tried so far

Comment: can you please post the raw data. this might be simpler as it looks right now... it could be a case of IIFs across the days over group by

Comment: i only need to display one month (June).

Comment: this are the raw data [link](https://ibb.co/gbYECa)

Comment: @Harry I tried using pivot and elimate the column day_number, and this is the ouptut [link](https://ibb.co/jAgjCa)

Comment: @Mumar Adam I'm a little confused.. it's the pivot doing what you want it to do already? Or are you looking to generate blank week days if not present in the raw data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOt NUll
Drop Table #Temp
 ;With cte( Month_Name , Day_Name , Year , Week_Number ,Day_number, emp_sched )
 AS
 (
 SELECT 'May' ,  'Sunday'  , 2017 , 4  , 28, '11:45-20:45' Union all
 SELECT 'May' , 'Tuesday'  , 2017 , 5  , 29, '14:15-23:15' Union all
 SELECT 'May' , 'Wednesday', 2017 , 5  , 30, '13:45-22:45' Union all
 SELECT 'June', 'Thursday' , 2017 , 1  ,  1,'10:00-19:00'  Union all
 SELECT 'June', 'Friday'   , 2017 , 1  ,  2,'10:00-19:00'  Union all
 SELECT 'June', 'Saturday' , 2017 , 1  ,  3,'10:00-19:00'
 )
 SELECT * INTo #Temp from cte


 Declare 
         @Sql nvarchar(max),
         @dynamicCol nvarchar(max),@dynamicCol2 nvarchar(max)

Declare @DynamicColumn Table (ID Int IDentity, WeekName varchar(20))
INsert Into @DynamicColumn(WeekName)
SELECT 'Monday'   Union all
SELECT 'Tuesday'  Union all
SELECT 'Wednesday'Union all
SELECT 'Thursday' Union all
SELECT 'Friday'   Union all
SELECT 'Saturday' Union all
SELECT 'Sunday'

SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT ', ' +WeekName FROM  @DynamicColumn
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

--SELECT @dynamicCol

SELECT @dynamicCol2=STUFF((SELECT ', ' + 'MAX('+ WeekName +')' +' Over(Order by Week_Number Asc ) AS ' 
+ WeekName  FROM  @DynamicColumn
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

--SELECT @dynamicCol2

SET @Sql='
SELECT Top 1 Week_Number,Month_Name,[Year], '+ @dynamicCol2 +' From
(
SELECT Month_Name,Day_Name,[Year],Week_Number,Day_number,[emp_sched] From
#temp
)AS Src
PIVOT 
(
MAX([emp_sched]) For [Day_Name ] IN ('+@dynamicCol+')
)
AS Pvt
'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

OutPut

```
Week_Number Month_Name  Year    Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday        Friday          Saturday        Sunday
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           June        2017    NULL    NULL    NULL        10:00-19:00     10:00-19:00     10:00-19:00     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 drop table if exists dbo.Schedule;

create table dbo.Schedule (
Month_Name varchar(100)
, Day_Name varchar(100)
, Year int
, Week_Number int
, Day_Number int
, emp_sched varchar(100)
);

insert into dbo.Schedule (Month_Name, Day_Name, Year, Week_Number, Day_Number, emp_sched)
values ('May', 'Sunday', 2017, 4           ,  28       ,  '11:45-20:45')
 , ('May'        ,  'Tuesday'  ,  2017 ,  5           ,  29       ,  '14:15-23:15')
 , ('May'        ,  'Wednesday',  2017 ,  5           ,  30       ,  '13:45-22:45')
 , ('June'       ,  'Thursday' ,  2017 ,  1           ,   1       , '10:00-19:00')
 , ('June'       ,  'Friday'   ,  2017 ,  1           ,   2       , '10:00-19:00')
 , ('June'       ,  'Saturday' ,  2017 ,  1           ,   3       , '10:00-19:00');


select
s.Week_Number, s.Month_Name, s.Year
, max(case when s.Day_Name = 'Monday' then s.emp_sched else '' end) as Monday
, max(case when s.Day_Name = 'Tuesday' then s.emp_sched else '' end) as Tuesday
, max(case when s.Day_Name = 'Wednesday' then s.emp_sched else '' end) as Wednesday
, max(case when s.Day_Name = 'Thursday' then s.emp_sched else '' end) as Thursday
, max(case when s.Day_Name = 'Friday' then s.emp_sched else '' end) as Friday
, max(case when s.Day_Name = 'Saturday' then s.emp_sched else '' end) as Saturday
from dbo.Schedule s
group by s.Week_Number, s.Month_Name, s.Year;
```